# How to upload a large file above 25 GB from client side jQuery?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I have a Web API project where there is an option in UI to upload large files 25 GB or above to server side. I have jQuery file control but it does not appear to support files larger than 2 GB.
What are the options to upload 25 GB files? Thank you!

Comment: What backend coding language do you use?

Comment: The backend language is C#.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [chunked file uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads)

Without them, you will most likely run out of memory (the file upload will be stored in memory during upload). If you do not have a web server with over 25 GB of memory, this will dramatically bring down the performance of your web server, and it may crash. At the very least, it will fail to upload.

You will also need this in your C# project, web config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="TTTTTT" maxRequestLength="XXXXXX" />
</system.web>
```

Where X is the Kilobyte value of your maximum chunk size, and T is the time in seconds that you want the connection to timeout if it exceeds.